# Symfony2:css, images and assetic

Tags: symfony

I've put a css file in `MyDirectoryBundle/Resources/public/css`.
I then linked to it using:

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/main.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I checked if it worked

```
short test: body {color: #FF0000;}
```

Nothing changed.

The parent layout (`layout.twig.html`) is in `app/Resources/views` (3 level architecture).

I still don't understand why:

- css does not work
- why the command: `php console assets:install web/ --symlink` fails
  -> answer: The target directory web does not exist. (it does exist, actually).

I am quite new to symfony2 (2 weeks practice only). 
I am working on Windows - just in case this may explain something...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: How are you pointing to your css file??

Comment: <link href="{{ asset('LV/IndexBundle/css/styles.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: try : php app/console instead of php console

Comment: I'm going to try that. thanks!

Comment: php app/console assets:install web/ --symlink worked. The resources were just copied. Message: "It looks like your system doesn't support symbolic links, so the assets were installed by copying them.

Answer (score 1):

1. If the file first lived in `MyDirectoryBundle/Resources/public/css`, it'll be copied to `web/bundles/mydirectory/css`. So you have to include it like: `{{ asset('bundles/mydirectory/css/main.css') }}`.
2. You should execute the command from the root of your project. As you're using `php console`, it seems like you're in the `app/` directory when executing this command. In that case, `app/web/` does not exists, so the error is completely valid.
3. As you're on Windows, there is a change that symlink is not allowed/available. I believe it's available for admins only since Windows vista.

As a side tip, if `MyDirectoryBundle` is your app bundle (a bundle tied to your app and not meant to be reused by other apps), I would recommend to put the CSS file in the `web/` directory directly. There is no need to put it in the bundle in such a case (this is only related to bundles that are shared, so the CSS is shared as well).

Answer (score 1):

use `php app/console` instead of `php console`